# Trigger ng-click using api

Tags: javascript, angularjs, api

I have a standard html form on Site A. When this form is submitted, using an api, I'm sending/submitting the information to a form on Site B. Site B has the same form, but uses ng-click to submit the form. So far I have not been able to successfully get Site B to submit the form using the api. Any help is appreciated

Site B's submit button:

```
<button class="btn btn-custom icon icon-only white check small flat ng-scope" ng-click="ProfileService.saveProfile(userProfileStates, $event)" ng-if="userProfileStates.edit"></button>
```

Comment: not clear .. please add some more details

Comment: You probably are getting cors error. Have you tried this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44503218/post-form-data-over-cross-domain-using-angular ?